# Inline if-else statement with multiple choices

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, inline

So, I was looking at the Inline if-statement, which taks use of the Ternary Operators. Basically this is my current code, which I want to make more compact.

```
private void Move(Vector3 direction) {
    if(direction != Vector3.back && direction != Vector3.forward) 
        transform.Rotate(0,(direction == Vector3.right ? 90 : -90),0);
    else 
        transform.Rotate(0,(direction == Vector3.back ? 180 : 0),0);

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward, Space.Self);
}
```

What I really want is something compacted like this:

```
private void Move(Vector3 direction) {
    transform.Rotate(0,(direction == Vector3.right ? 90 : -90 || direction == Vector3.back ? 180 : 0),0);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward, Space.Self);
}
```

Is there anyway to do this? Just take this an example. I want to know how to compact multiple inline if-statements, so I don't have to have more lines of code for no reason, if I can avoid it.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but in the interest of making the method more compact, perhaps try this:

```
public enum Direction
{
   Left = -90,
   Right = 90,
   Forward =0,
   Back = 180
}

private void Move(Direction direction) 
{
   transform.Rotate(0,(int)direction,0);
   transform.Translate(Vector3.forward, Space.Self);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Very compact, very expandable. I appreciate it, I didn't even think of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that first one is compact enough. If the `Vector3` enumeration has 4 values, your second example won't work. And making it work may look just as long as the first example.

```
private void Move(Vector3 direction)
{
    transform.Rotate(0,
        direction == Vector3.right ? 90 :
            (direction == Vector3.left ? -90
                (direction == Vector3.back ? 180 : 0)), 0);
    ...
}
```

A ternary operation is most "compact" when you have only two values to test.

For example:

```
Color color;

if (title == "VIP")
    color = Color.Red;
else
    color = Color.Blue;
```

Becomes:

```
var color = (title == "VIP" ? Color.Red : Color.Blue);
```

Comment: Your method is correct, but not very compact. Which is why I didn't choose your answer based on the compactability and expandability. The answer below was the one I accepted, since the idea of it is simple, compact, and exandable. But I appreciate your time and effort tho!